# Making library name part of include path in make?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

Say I'm working on a library, foo. Within my libraries source files, I'd like to include headers the same way a user of my library would:

```
#include <foo/bar.hpp>

// code defining bar methods here
```

In boost for example, includes of other headers within boost are done that way, e.g. `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`, rather than the relative quoted `"../shared_ptr.hpp"` style. I looked at how some other libraries accomplish this and it appears they add a redundant directory to their file layout in order to do it, e.g. the boost code lives in "boost_1_4_1/boost" rather than just "boost_1_4_1/".

Switching to that scheme is annoying if you already have source control using an existing layout. What's the best way with GNU make to layer it on? My only thought is to add a target that all build targets depend on that makes a hidden folder with a symlink inside to my source tree, and add that hidden folder to the include path. Perhaps there's a less obfuscated way?

Comment: the best way IS to have the "redundant" directory. What source control are you using that makes this problematic?

Comment: I just gave source control as an example, I imagine it would be a pain with say CVS, at least if you didn't have access to rename directories on the server. But also it makes all of your paths longer, in your editor, in your shell etc.

Comment: If you want to use a symlink, why go through the process of having the makefile create a hidden symlink? And why hidden? On unix systems, the hidden directory symlink wouldn't be named `foo` since it would have to start with a period - causing your workaround to not work.  Just make a symlink (and add it to you source control) if that's what you want to do to avoid actually moving the files.  But I think it would be better to just move the files; it often  confuses me when files apparently live in two place, so only do it when there's a really good reason.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: The idea is to make a hidden directory with a normal (unhidden) symlink inside, and add the hidden directory to the include path. By making it its own folder with only that symlink inside you can be sure that the only thing that you're adding to your include path is the source tree. You could make it a normal symlink just in the root of the source tree pointing to '.', and adding the source tree to your include path, but then you end up being able to do <buzz.h> if buzz.h is in your root source folder, instead of being forced to do <foo/buzz.h> (preferable).

Comment: I still don't see why you're trying to do it this way. If the problem is long paths in the editor and command line, make a symlink shortcut for use by the editor and command line, *not* the compiler. If the problem is source control, bite the bullet and update the paths in the archive-- you only have to do it once; and if you don't have the authority to do that, give the job to the person who does; and if that person won't help you, then you've got bigger problems than `include` paths.

Comment: @Beta: Setting up a symlink for shorter editor and command line paths doesn't work great in practice because some editors resolve the symlink and you just have the longer path again (my emacs using ido-mode has this problem, I've tried to debug it but it's a PITA). There's also the annoyance for every developer on the project to do that independently. And I'm just intuitively irked by the idea that I have to make an extra folder to get sane behavior. If you have say 10 libraries in your source tree, to get proper includes you have to have foo/foo, bar/bar, buzz/buzz, etc which just seems dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use -I gcc key of INC option for your Makefile?

gcc:

> gcc -c -I/home/joseph/dev/foo/headers

Makefile:

```
INC=-I/home/joseph/dev/foo/headers
```

In this case you would have only one place to make this change, Makefile.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem of allowing him to use `#include "foo/bar.hpp"` in order to pick up a `bar.hpp` that doesn't actually live in a directory named `foo`.